# How to add additions in a cocoa touch static library

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm writing a simple static library for myself recently. It include some ui control, macro, and additions of cocoa touch class, but there's something wrong with my code, and I don't know how to solve it.

I did these steps:

1. create a cocoa touch static library project named Orange, just for test.
2. add a NSObject subclass named MyMath, implement code.
3. add 2 files for NSArray addition, implement code.
4. move the project directory to "/".
5. create a window based application named TestOrange.
6. drag the Orange.xcodeproj into TestOrange.
7. set header search paths to "/Orange/Orange"
8. set Build Phases like the image bellow showed.
   [image]

when i run the TestOrange, it can print the result of MyMath, but crash immediately.
[image]

MyMath can work, but NSArrayAdditions can't work. I think there's something wrong with NSArrayAdditions.

anyone encountered this problem before? please help me.

thanks in advance.

all code have listed here.
MyMath

```
@interface MyMath : NSObject {
}
- (NSNumber*)AddA:(int)a B:(int)b;
@end

@implementation MyMath
- (NSNumber*)AddA:(int)a B:(int)b {
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:a+b];
}
@end
```

NSArrayAdditions

```
@interface NSArray (Additions)
- (NSNumber*)Double:(int)a;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Additions)
- (NSNumber*)Double:(int)a {
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:2*a];
}
@end
```

use libOrange

```
#import "TestOrangeAppDelegate.h"

#import "MyMath.h"
#import "NSArrayAdditions.h"
@implementation TestOrangeAppDelegate
@synthesize window=_window;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MyMath *mm = [[MyMath alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", [mm AddA:12 B:23]);
    [mm release];

    NSArray *ary = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", [ary Double:13]);
    [ary release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `-ObjC` and `-load_all` to your "other linker flags" in your build settings.
Basically, categories on framework classes don't necessarily get linked in unless you specify this flag.
`-load_all` will force the loading of all compiled classes, which solves the problem.

Comment: I know this is solved, but just to clarify, it should be `-all_load` (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html) instead of `-load_all`.